# How do I check if I am using GPU on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, gpu

I am training a NN using keras in a deep learning AMI (ubuntu 12) in AWS.

How do I ensure that my script in Jupyter Notebook is using GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the session in tensorflow you could add this line of code to check:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

For further detail of using GPU with tensorflow, you could check it out on tensorflow official website: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu